# show tab bar on pop using hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, popviewcontrolleranimated

I want to show tab bar only on parent controllers not on any of the child.

I'm doing this on push:

```
childViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(childViewController!, animated: true)
```

Now, when I navigate back by clicking 'Back' button the bar is shown agin on parent.

But if I do the same programatically like this:

```
childViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
//or
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Then the tab bar is not shown again on parent.

I have already tried many solutions like;

Solution 1:
writing this code in child

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true 
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false 
}
```

Solution 2: writing this code on push

```
childViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(childViewController!, animated: true)
childViewController?.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

None of it worked. Everything works well if I navigate back with navigation bar back button.
But if I `popViewController` or `popToRootViewController` then it doesn't works.

> Using: XCode 8.3.2, Swift 3

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way in the controller in which you want to hide:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
}
```